# Generate The Raw MySQL Query From Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can i get `mysql` query of a `laravel` query

**Convert:**

```
App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...)->get();
```

**To:**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE `balance`>0 and ...
```

Comment: my answer replace parameters ? with binding values

Comment: @honarkhah thanks for answering... my problem solved with RAUSHAN KUMAR's answer

Comment: What is your purpose for get query ?

Comment: @HirendrasinhS.Rathod I used this to execute my query on my node.js server

Comment: to execute it on node.js server use solution mention here http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/display-all-sql-executed-in-eloquent

otherwise i have one crazy idea to view query on web page but that may not help you.

Comment: @HirendrasinhS.Rathod Thanks. Problem solved 10 month ago

Answer (score 50, accepted):

use `toSql()` method of laravel to get the query to be executed like

```
App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...)->toSql();
```

But Laravel will not show you parameters in your query, because they are bound after preparation of the query. To get the bind parameters, use this

```
$query=App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...);
print_r($query->getBindings() );
```

enable the query log as `DB::enableQueryLog()` and then output to the screen the last queries ran you can use this,

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: this method replaces parameters with `?` mark.

``select * from `users` where `balance` > ?``

Comment: @543310 yes, because that gives raw query, for dynamic data it puts `?` so you can give your own value in place of `?` and directly execute

Comment: is there a way to get query with parameters?

Comment: if not, how can i add parameters to this raw query?

Comment: You can use like this `$query=App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...)->toSql(); print_r( $query->getBindings() );` to get the bind parameters

Comment: This is a solution that "optionally works". Check my answer

Answer (score 7):

you can add this function to your helpers

```
function getRealQuery($query, $dumpIt = false)
{
    $params = array_map(function ($item) {
        return "'{$item}'";
    }, $query->getBindings());
    $result = str_replace_array('\?', $params, $query->toSql());
    if ($dumpIt) {
        dd($result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

---

and use like this:

```
getRealQuery(App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...),true)
```

Comment: Your welcome .. , i created this because its very useful

Comment: Note that `?` might be part of a string.

Comment: @paul-spiegel replace all ?  with bindings values

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR you started bounty but not using them , why?

Comment: @honarkhah You need to distinguish between placeholders and `?` in a string like here: `->selectRaw("'How are you?' AS message")`. For a reliable solution you will need (kind of) an SQL parser.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yes you right , i searching to find solution for this situation

Answer (score 4):

To print the raw sql query, try:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
// Your query here
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
print_r($queries);
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)

Comment: yeah, the same thing i mentioned above

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1

To print a single query, use toSql() method of laravel to get the query to be executed like

```
App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...)->toSql();
```

### Method 2

Laravel can optionally log in memory all queries that have been run for the current request. But in some cases, such as when inserting a large number of rows, this can cause the application to use excess memory, so you should avoid this.

To enable the log, you may use the **enableQueryLog** method as

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

To get an array of the executed queries, you may use the **getQueryLog** method as

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

you can get more details here [Laravel Enable Query Log](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging)

### Method 3

Another approach to display all queries used in Laravel without enabling the query log install the **LaravelDebugBar** from here [Laravel Debug Bar](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-debugbar).
It is a package that allows you to quickly and easily keep tabs on your application during development.

Comment: \DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
     .. QUERY
        $queries = \DB::getQueryLog(); AWESOOME

Answer (score 3):

Here is a helper function who tells you the last SQL executed.

```
use DB;
public static function getLastSQL()
{
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    $last_query = end($queries);
          // last_query is the SQL with with data binding like 
          //   { 
          //       select ? from sometable where field = ? and field2 = ? ;
          //       param1,
          //       param2，
          //       param3，
          //   }
          //   which is hard to read.
    $last_query = bindDataToQuery($last_query);     
          // here, last_query is the last SQL you have executed as normal SQL
          //     select param1 from sometable where field=param2 and field2 = param3;
    return $last_query
}
```

Here is the bindDataToQuery function, who fill the '?' blanks with real params.

```
protected static function bindDataToQuery($queryItem){
    $query = $queryItem['query'];
    $bindings = $queryItem['bindings'];
    $arr = explode('?',$query);
    $res = '';
    foreach($arr as $idx => $ele){
        if($idx < count($arr) - 1){
            $res = $res.$ele."'".$bindings[$idx]."'";
        }
    }
    $res = $res.$arr[count($arr) -1];
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: yeah, the same thing i mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

It is so strange that the laravel haven't support any way to get the raw sql easily, it is now version 6 after all...

Here's a workaround I used by myself to quickly get the raw sql with parameters without installing any extension...

Just deliberately make your original sql WRONG

Like change

```
DB::table('user')
```

to

```
DB::table('user1')
```

where the table "user1" does not exist at all!

Then run it again.

Sure there will be an exception reported by laravel.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user1' doesn't exist (SQL: ...)
```

And now you can see the raw sql with parameters is right after the string "(SQL:"

Change back from the wrong table name to the right one and there you go!

Answer (score 2):

To get mysql query in laravel you need to log your query as

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...)->get();
print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Check reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

Comment: yeah, the same thing i mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5.4 (I didn't check this in other versions), add this function into the 
"App"=>"Providers"=>"AppServiceProvider.php" .

```
public function boot()
{

    if (App::isLocal()) {

        DB::listen(
            function ($sql) {
                // $sql is an object with the properties:
                //  sql: The query
                //  bindings: the sql query variables
                //  time: The execution time for the query
                //  connectionName: The name of the connection

                // To save the executed queries to file:
                // Process the sql and the bindings:
                foreach ($sql->bindings as $i => $binding) {
                    if ($binding instanceof \DateTime) {
                        $sql->bindings[$i] = $binding->format('\'Y-m-d H:i:s\'');
                    } else {
                        if (is_string($binding)) {
                            $sql->bindings[$i] = "'$binding'";
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Insert bindings into query
                $query = str_replace(array('%', '?'), array('%%', '%s'), $sql->sql);

                $query = vsprintf($query, $sql->bindings);

                // Save the query to file
                /*$logFile = fopen(
                    storage_path('logs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . date('Y-m-d') . '_query.log'),
                    'a+'
                );*/
                Log::notice("[USER] $query");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

After that install,
https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer
and then you can see every executed SQL queries without editing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of interfering with the application with print statements or "`dd`s", I do the following when I want to see the generated SQL:

```
DB::listen(function ($query) { 
    Log::info($query->sql, $query->bindings);
});

// (DB and Log are the facades in Illuminate\Support\Facades namespace)
```

This will output the sql to the Laravel log (located at `storage/logs/laravel.log`). A useful command for following writes to this file is

```
tail -n0 -f storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to display all queries used in Laravel without any code changes at all is to install the LaravelDebugBar (https://laravel-news.com/laravel-debugbar).

As part of the functionality you get a tab which will show you all of the queries that a page has used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$results = App\User::where('balance','>',0)->where(...)->toSql();
dd($results);
```

Note: get() has been replaced with toSql() to display the raw SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and shortcut way is below
Write the name of column wrong like write 'balancedd' in spite of 'balance' and the query will be displayed on error screen when you execute code with all the parameters and error that column not found.

Answer (score 0):

`DB::enableQueryLog();
(Query)
$d= DB::getQueryLog(); print"<pre>"; print_r ($d); print"</pre>";`

you will get the mysql query that is just run.

Answer (score -3):

There is actually no such thing in Laravel and even PHP, since PHP internally sends the parameters with query string to the database where it (possibly) become parsed into raw query string.

The accepted answer is actually optimistic solution, kind of "optionally works".