# laravel dump model query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a model class query

my code

```
  $jobs = \App\Job::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->offset($start)->limit($length)->get(); //supply start and length of the table data
```

I tried 
DB::enableQueryLog();
dd( DB::getQueryLog() );

but it is showing nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel query to sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497115/laravel-query-to-sql-query)

Comment: Checkout this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your somewhere before you run your query:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    dump($sql);
});
```

Depending on the namespace of where you put the above you might have to import the `DB` facade or simply change it to `\DB`.

Hope this helps!